# Retrieve top headlines from Apple News API

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-news

I'm willing to access the top news available in the Apple News app, but it seems the related API only allows users (publishers) to access the content of their own channel. Does someone know a working endpoint or have any other idea to help me reach my goal (maybe a complete lists of channels' IDs currently allowed in  the app?).

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct that the purpose of the API is for content creators:

> Use the Apple News API to publish and manage Apple News Format
>   articles.

It does not provide a way for developers to distribute articles from other content creators. For iTunes, Apple's own in-house news, and for Movie trailers, [RSS feeds are available](https://www.apple.com/rss/). There is even an [RSS refiner for iTunes](https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us) but currently no Apple News equivalent that I am aware of. Whether in future Apple News will be supported in this way I don't know, it will be depend on how they handle the rights of creators.